# Spring exception - NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property

Tags: spring

I'm trying to create a form to add an object into the database.

The model for the form

```
  public class Module implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8825646974241476909L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "module_id")
private Long moduleId;

@Column(name = "module_code")
private String moduleCode;

@Column(name = "module_name")
private String moduleName;


//getters and setters

 public Long getModuleId() {
    return moduleId;
}

public void setModuleId(Long moduleId) {
    this.moduleId = moduleId;
}

public String getModuleCode() {
    return moduleCode;
}

public void setModuleCode(String moduleCode) {
    this.moduleCode = moduleCode;
}

public String getModuleName() {
    return moduleName;
}

public void setModuleName(String moduleName) {
    this.moduleName = moduleName;
}
```

The form

```
   <c:url var="saveUrl" value="/admin/addModule" />
     <form:form modelAttribute="module" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}" name="module">

    <table>

        <tr>
        <td><form:hidden path="moduleId"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><form:label path="moduleCode">Module Code:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="moduleCode"/></td>
        </tr>


</table>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
</form:form>
```

Controller

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/addModule", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAdminAddModule(@ModelAttribute("module") ModelMap map) {
map.addAttribute("module", new Module());

    // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/addedpage.jsp
return "/admin/addModule";
}
```

When I try to access the form an error keeps coming up on all of the properties. This is the stacktrace error for the moduleId property.

```
   org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'moduleCode' of bean class [org.springframework.ui.ModelMap]: Bean property 'moduleCode' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:709)
org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:701)
org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:218)
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.admin.addModule_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(addModule_jsp.java:452)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.admin.addModule_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(addModule_jsp.java:363)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.admin.addModule_jsp._jspService(addModule_jsp.java:151)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:108)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:64)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:65)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

I have all of the setter and getters but the error is persistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `@ModelAttribute` against `ModelMap` parameter. That parameter is automatically populated by Spring and gives you a way of populating the model objects, which you are later doing with `map.addAttribute("module", new Module());`.

Removing `@ModelAttribute` should fix it for you.